# Send html content in email body of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I want to add the html file inside the email body through jenkins. The problem is the email is receiving as plain text. And i have one more problem. That html file has several dependent html files. How to add that all? Orelse can i send an excel content inside the email body?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
[Email Extn jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).

To send html file in email, please select content type as html.
And in content please mention the html file path.
[Image showing content as html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgaRA.jpg)

Comment: While doing so, the html tags are also added. It is coming as a plain text. No styles are applied

Comment: can u post ur settings here, i am using the same and it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Email Extn jenkins plugin should get you sailing. Set the content type to either HTML/Plain text or HTML.

The body can contain your HTML code/File. Make sure the start and end tags are crisp.

One of the reason styles are not applied may be due to incorrect relative paths to the style files wrt HTML in the jenkins workspace.